# REST API HTTP CallOut error in same domain

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using this code to call a REST API inside my same domain

```
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        req.setEndpoint('https://chaarvim-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/composite/tree/Account/');
        req.setMethod('POST');        
        req.setCompressed(false);
        req.setBody(strRequest);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());


        try {
            res = http.send(req);         
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
        }
```

But i am getting

`[{"message":"This session is not valid for use with the REST API","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]`

Any Suggestions please.

Comment: are you calling it from LWC component?

Comment: your code worked for me

Comment: @User6670 is there any settings to do

Comment: no setting i just put your code on anonymous window and changed the address and put the record in "strRequest" variable and executed it and it created a record for me

Comment: Let me check.Thanks